# why doesn't python 3.6.1 recognize numpy or pil or skimage after they have been successfully installed

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting these errors trying to run a python3 program in itelliJ IDEA on a mac.

```
import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

from PIL import Image, ImageChops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

from skimage.feature import match_template # requires numpy, scipy, and six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
```

All of these modules have been successfully installed using pip3. I have confirmed the installs using IDLE. Clearly, it seems, there is more to it than simply installing, but I don't know what it is.

I cannot find anything that addresses concerns on python.org. They, in fact, refer me to Stackoverflow. The closest I found here dealt with numpy and python2.7 on mac. There are no responses to that one.

Comment: Check your python path, python needs to know where the packages you installed are to fetch them. (This is usually done automatically, but that would be the first thing to check IMO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Preferences for the `Project Interpreter` setting, and make sure it's pointing to the right python version.

Secondly, since you're already using and IDE use PyCharm. It's IntelliJ's python specific IDE, and it'll have better documentation on python specific technical problems.

Comment: "use PyCharm" is totally opinion based. I could very well tell you to use Spyder which has my personal preference...

Comment: This was the problem. I was pointing to the wrong version of the interpreter. Thank you Dwaxe. As for PyCharm, I have the community version - no help (or at least I couldn't find the help). After speaking with Jet Brains I determined my best stategy (IMHO) was to focus on ItelliJ IDEA, using the Python plugins, since I work on Python projects, JavaScript projects and WordPress projects. I am hoping one tool fits all well enough.